# undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass using group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass
```

I've whittled down the issue for the problem i'm having and it's relating the the group section of my scope as when I remove the group options it works, but not as i intend. Is there a way to past over the nil records in my loop? I've tried the `try` method below, but still have the same issue.

I have also tried `group.try(:assessmentDate)` but get the following error:

```
The method .group() must contain arguments.
```

**Model**

```
class EstablishmentMethod < ApplicationRecord
  scope :assessment_date, -> { group('assessmentDate').group('treatment_selection_id').order(:treatment_selection_id).order("assessmentDate ASC") }
end
```

**Index**

```
<% data.establishmentMethods.order(:treatment_selection_id).try(:assessment_date).in_groups_of(3)[i].each_with_index do |e, index| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is `i` in `data.establishmentMethods.order(:treatment_selection_id).try(:assessment_date).in_groups_of(3)[i]` ? This evaluates to `nil` most probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[in_groups_of](https://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) uses for grouping by given number an array. You seen this error, because it's normal if your array's length is less than 3. For example:

```
irb(main):003:0> %w(1 2).in_groups_of(3)
=> [["1", "2", nil]]
```

You're iterating a group like `["1", "2", nil]` if `i` is an index number. But if `i` not in index range of your array, you'll choose a `nil` object. For example:

```
irb(main):003:0> gr = %w(1 2).in_groups_of(3)
=> [["1", "2", nil]]
irb(main):004:0> gr[3]
=> nil
```

And then you'll see following error when using `each_with_index`.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no need of `[i]` here

```
 <% data.establishmentMethods.order(:treatment_selection_id).try(:assessment_date).in_groups_of(3).each_with_index do |e, index| %>
    ...
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to do with the value of [i] You are probably supposed to use a nested loop here (depending on what the problem is you're trying to solve)

```
<% data.establishmentMethods.order(:treatment_selection_id).try(:assessment_date).in_groups_of(3).each_with_index do |e, index_a| %>
    <% e.each_with_index do |elem,index_b| %>
     ...
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you need to keep the [i] there (e.g if there is an outer loop) ensure that the maximum value for [i] is set to:

```
max_i =  (data.establishmentMethods.order(:treatment_selection_id).try(:assessment_date).length.to_f)/(3.to_f)).ceil
```